# Finding ids that have not yet been assigned in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a one-to-one relation between my webscrapers and a list of proxies. Now I'd like to know what proxies are still available to be assigned to a webscraper.

**bots**

[image]

**proxies**

[image]

I basically need the `id`s of `proxies` that have not yet been assigned to a `bots` row. I've been quite rusty with my SQL but I was thinking this would just be a simple join but performing the following join just resulted me into all rows being spat back at me;`

`SELECT DISTINCT proxies.* FROM proxies JOIN bots ON bots.proxy_id <> proxies.id;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to subqueries is an outer join, and then search for cases where there is no match, i.e the outer join produced NULL in the matching table.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM proxies AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN bot AS b ON b.proxy_id = p.id
WHERE b.proxy_id IS NULL;
```

You can try both this solution and the subquery solution given by @GordonLinoff on this thread, and see which one performs better against your data.

Comment: As I do not expect either of my tables to have over a hundred rows - I don't think performance will be an issue. I don't really have a preference for either, they both work perfectly (: 

Edit: I actually might prefer this one as this is not giving me a hard time trying to access other values from the same row.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM proxies p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM bots b
                  WHERE b.proxy_id = p.id
                 );
```

Basically, this says "Get me all proxies that have no bot with that proxie id".

Comment: Ofcourse, subqueries. I really need to dig into some SQL again. Thanks a lot this works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM PROXIES p
  WHERE p.ID NOT IN (SELECT b.PROXY_ID
                       FROM BOTS b)
```